# Fit image on p-galleria primeNg for Angular2 application

Tags: css, image, angular, fixed, primeng

I used p_galleria of PrimeNg and set this attributes :

```
<p-galleria [images]="productImages"
   panelWidth="560"
   panelHeight="313"
   autoPlay="false"
   showFilmstrip="false"
   id="product-galley"
   showCaption="false">
</p-galleria>
```

also I added an style for rendered image panel :

```
.ui-panel-images {
    /*height: inherit !important;
    width: inherit !important;*/
    /*max-height: inherit !important;
    height: initial;
    max-width: inherit !important;
    width: initial;*/
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
}
```

But the image is always stretched in container, I want it to be fixed in scale. and be in center of panel.

Is there any idea how to change the style?

> Maybe its not relevant, but I wrapped this gallery in a
>   bootstrap-modal.

Answer (score 3):

Using primeng v6.0.0, I added this to my CSS to make the image resize itself, keeping the aspect ratio, to match the dimensions of the p-galleria container.

```css
.ui-panel-images {
  width      : 100%;
  height     : 100%;
  object-fit : contain;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the previous solutions worked for me. My solution for a responsive galleria panel was to size a responsive container element and fit the panel attributes to the container:

```
<div #container>
  <p-galleria [panelWidth]="container.offsetWidth" 
  [panelHeight]="container.offsetHeight" 
  [images]="images"></p-galleria>
</div>
```

What was especially helpful in my case, was to set my container to 100% width, and calculate an aspect ratio to match my images. Note, you don't need to set a container height in this method. Optionally, you could add more height if you're showing a filmstrip:

```
<div #container>
  <p-galleria [panelWidth]="container.offsetWidth" 
  [panelHeight]="container.offsetWidth * (5/16)"
  [images]="images" [showFilmstrip]="false"></p-galleria>
</div>
```

For the object-fit to work, I had to override the view encapsulation like so:

```
:host ::ng-deep img.ui-panel-images {
  object-fit: contain !important;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-md-5">
<p-galleria [images]="imagesGaleria"
            styleClass="completa"
            [showFilmstrip]="false"
            [showCaption]="false"
            effectDuration=2000></p-galleria>
```

And my css, there are some properties that you can remove

```
.completa { 
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
z-index: -100;
-ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
background-size: cover;} 


.ui-panel-images{
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
/*z-index: -100;*/
-ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
/*background-size: cover;*/}
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above works for me. Also, there was a little hiccup with the close button—it decided to play hide and seek behind the picture, making it tricky to close the pic. This is how I fixed it (just a hack):

```
// prime ng galleria bugs fix
::ng-deep .p-galleria-thumbnail-items.p-items-hidden .p-galleria-thumbnail-item {
  visibility: visible;
}

::ng-deep p-galleriacontent {
  width: 100%
}

::ng-deep p-galleriaitem img {
  width: fit-content;
  height: 80vh;
}

::ng-deep .p-button-label {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

::ng-deep .p-galleria-close {
  z-index: 100002;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refering to near perfect answer of user sawprogramming. The code should be wrapped in

```
:host {
  ::ng-deep {
    .ui-panel-images {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: contain;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked fine.

```
`            .ui-panel-images {
            width: auto;
            height: inherit;
            object-fit: contain;
            position: relative;
        }
```

`